# Can I make GIF animation frames play faster in ActionScript?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, performance, frames, gif

like say i have a gif that has 10 frames. what is the code that will help me make the gif go through those frames at a quicker pace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pull each frame from the GIF and place them om the timeline and then det the framerate of the movieto whatever you like

Answer (score 0):

You set the framerate in the file properties (by clicking on the empty background).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to increase your animation's FPS rate, you can't do it by code. The .fla framerate is defined by the field FPS, located in the Properties panel of the animation.

You can use the EnterFrame event of Actionscript to control the flow of your animation, but even with it you can't change the framerate.

Child movies will inherits the framerate's parent movie.

Comment: I am assuming you mean you can't change the framerate of a gif, but just so its clear for others, the SWF frame rate itself can be changed by code: stage.frameRate

Comment: No, I meant the SWF framerate, but I didn't know about this property. Taking a look at the Adobe Documentation, you're right, the SWF framerate can be changed. Thank you for the information, btw =)
But I guess the framerate's child movies will be the same as the main movie.